# Comparing two arrays in php laravel

Tags: php

so I have this code:

```
    $org_user_profile = OrgUser::where('user_id',$current_user->uuid)->first();
    $profile_org_relation = Organization::where('uuid',$org_user_profile->organization_id)->pluck('name');

    $sample = array("Water");

    if ($profile_org_relation == $sample) {
    return 'henlo';

    } else {
       throw new AccessDeniedHttpException(
       'User does not have an administrator access'
       );
    }
```

I have tried to return the values of `$profile_org_relation` and `$sample` and they are exactly alike. then why does it fall into the else?

I tried `var_dump($profile_org_relation === $sample);` and it returned `bool(false)` but why?

Comment: I'm not a PHP person but isn't `$profile_org_relation` a string and `$sample` is an array. Don't you need to compare against the first value within the $sample array to return the string `Water`?? It could be evaluating false because comparing string to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer to my dumb question, turns out that when you pluck, the type would be an object. and I am comparing it to an array so it would really return bool(false) so I converted the object to array before comparing again and now it works.

```
$objtoarray = $profile_org_relation->toArray();
```

then

```
if ($objtoarray === $sample) {
```